# go-sql-driver/mysql uses hostname rather than IP

Tags: mysql, go, driver

I have *server1* and *server2*. On *server1* I have a Go app, trying to connect to MySQL on *server2*.

Here are the IPs: 
*server1* 10.127.8.160;
*server2* 10.127.8.161

I get the following error:

```
Error 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'server1' (using password: NO)
```

This is the connection string i am using:

```
root:@(10.127.8.161:3306)/mydatabase
```

The password for root is empty string. I also tried 'root@' (without the column) with the same result. I don't think this is important, but I figured I should mention it.

This is what I have in *server2*. I have privileges for *server1*, but only by IP. The connection comes from *server1* by hostname instead.

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@10.127.8.160                         |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'10.127.8.160' |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

The question is how do I make it connect using its IP not its hostname? I don't have much control over *server2* to add more privileges.

And for completeness this are the privileges for hostname:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'server1'    
ERROR 1141 (42000) at line 1: There is no such grant defined for user 'root' on host 'server1'
```

Link to the driver:
https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql

Thanks

Comment: The connection string is irrelevant. What matters is DNS resolution on the MySQL server itself.

Comment: This let's me in from server1: mysql -h 10.127.8.161 -u root